# What is the proper aria-label for a link that will open and play a video?

Tags: html, accessibility

I have JS that will be handling videos and there are `anchor` tags with an icon in them on the page which, when clicked, will open a video. How can I make this more accessible through aria?

HTML:

```
<a href="myvideo.webm" class="video"><img src="myimage.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set an `alt` attribute on the `img`. `aria` will only be useful for supporting screenreader users which only covers less than 1% of the population.

See [H30: Providing link text that describes the purpose of a link for anchor elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H30.html)

> When an image is the only content of a link, the text alternative for the image describes the unique function of the link.

```
<a href="myvideo.webm" class="video">
    <img src="myimage.png" alt="insert something descriptive here">
</a>
```

Comment: Exactly this. For the alt content I'd suggest something like "Open video in a new tab" or the name of the video.